# Protobuf-net: How to debug "Nested or jagged lists and arrays are not supported"

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

During serialization I've got the following error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Nested or jagged lists and arrays are not supported
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.ResolveListTypes(TypeModel model, Type type, Type& itemType, Type& defaultType)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.ApplyDefaultBehaviour(Boolean isEnum, ProtoMemberAttribute normalizedAttribute)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.ApplyDefaultBehaviour()
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.FindOrAddAuto(Type type, Boolean demand, Boolean addWithContractOnly, Boolean addEvenIfAutoDisabled)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.GetKey(Type type, Boolean demand, Boolean getBaseKey)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.ValueMember.TryGetCoreSerializer(RuntimeTypeModel model, DataFormat dataFormat, Type type, WireType& defaultWireType, Boolean asReference, Boolean dynamicType, Boolean overwriteList, Boolean allowComplexTypes)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.ValueMember.BuildSerializer()
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.BuildSerializer()
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.get_Serializer()
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_20(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteRecursionSafeObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_6(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteRecursionSafeObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_5(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_84(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteRecursionSafeObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_32(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteRecursionSafeObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_5(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.WriteNetObject(Object value, ProtoWriter dest, Int32 key, NetObjectOptions options)
   at proto_150(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteRecursionSafeObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_147(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_26(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteRecursionSafeObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_6(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteRecursionSafeObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_5(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_8(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteRecursionSafeObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_6(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteRecursionSafeObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_5(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.WriteNetObject(Object value, ProtoWriter dest, Int32 key, NetObjectOptions options)
   at proto_142(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteRecursionSafeObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_141(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_139(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.WriteNetObject(Object value, ProtoWriter dest, Int32 key, NetObjectOptions options)
   at proto_80(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteRecursionSafeObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_32(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteRecursionSafeObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_5(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_137(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer)
   at proto_1(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeCore(ProtoWriter writer, Object value)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(Stream dest, Object value, SerializationContext context)
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize[T](Stream destination, T instance)
```

I see the problem, but where, what type? Any suggestion how to find it?

I've tried to search `Dictionary<` `List<` and take a look what inside it, but no luck.

`InnerException` is `null`

I've tried to call `ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.GetSchema(typeof(LinkBudgetScenario));` the same not helpful message.

Is it possible to get a more helpful error message and not internal useless for debugging message?

Comment: How about if you debug in Visual Studio, turn on "Break when exception is thrown" and then examine the parameters on that call stack? You probably won't have the source, but the parameters should still be easily available. Failing that, you could check out protobuf-net from github and add it to your solution, and thus have the source code available as well.

Comment: @DarkFalcon, I've source code, but the source object is really huge. I've tried to bring protobuf source code, but there's another issue. Protobuf on VS 2017, our project on VS 15. Yes, I can install VS 17, convert our project to VS 17. Just, wanted to know, maybe there's the easy way :)

Comment: I've found the issue, thanks to .Net reflector. It allows debugging third party libraries. BTW it was `List<Lobe2d>[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

1. update to protobuf-net 2.3.0: https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/2.3.0
2. re-run your code and read the message

Comment: Is it possible to improve the error: `Multi-dimensional arrays are not supported` too? Currently, it does not say where the error, what field :(

Answer (score 1):

Steps to resolve the issue:

1. Try to take a look at the source object. (if no luck `goto 2`)
2. Bring `Protobuf-net` source code to your solution (if no luck `goto 3`)
3. Install `.net reflector` and turn on the ability to debug, don't forget to stop on all exceptions (`Debug` -> `Windows` -> `Exception Settings`). Now you're able to identify the problem type.